# Perl - exit with constant

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict "vars";
use warnings;
use feature qw(switch);

use locale;
use POSIX qw(locale_h);
setlocale(LC_ALL, "cs_CZ.UTF-8");

use constant (
    ERROR_OK => 0,
    ERROR_CMD => 1,
    ERROR_INPUT => 2,
    ERROR_OUTPUT => 3,
    ERROR_INPUT_FORMAT => 4
);

exit ERROR_OUTPUT;
```

I am still getting error "Argument "ERROR_OUTPUT" isn't numeric in exit at ... "
How can i use constant for exit values instead of directy use of numbers?

Comment: ERROR_OUTPUT, or ERROR_OUTPUTS?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the parentheses after `use constant` to curlies.

```
use constant {
    ERROR_OK => 0,
    # etc.
};
```

Comment: It is weird that wrong declaration does not cause even warnings. +1

Comment: @w.k: It is not actually wrong. Try printing or `Data::Dumper`ing ERROR_OK.

Comment: @w.k: Are you sure? I am getting a different result.

Comment: To be exact, i tried `print ERROR_INPUT` and got verbatim output, now with  ERROR_OK was output `9`. Pretty confusing.

Comment: @w.k: I am still getting something else :-) It is passed as arguments to `constant->import`, anyway.

Comment: How? I use script OP offered, just inserted print statements, like `print ERROR_OK . "\n";`

Comment: @w.k: Concatenation forces scalar context.

Comment: @w.k You should actually do the thing suggested rather than some other thing which, while related, does not actually fulfill the purpose.  In this case, that thing is `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper ERROR_OK;`.

Comment: @darch: thank you for pointing, but choroba suggested print **or** Dumper. I tried first one (and before choroba's suggestions). Dumpering would be good too.

Comment: @w.k You're right.  In which case, that command is `print ERROR_OK;` or at most `print ERROR_OK, "\n";`.  Not the one you used.

Answer (score 4):

A `use constant` directive should use `{`curly braces`}`, not `(`parentheses`)`.

```
use constant {
    ERROR_OK => 0,
    ERROR_CMD => 1,
    ERROR_INPUT => 2,
    ERROR_OUTPUT => 3,
    ERROR_INPUT_FORMAT => 4
};
```

Comment: More to the point, the constants he is setting up require braces.  Parens work dandy for their documented use case.